# KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, digital-signature

I'm trying to send HTTPS request from my Java EE program to the host that requires certificate authentication. I have a proper keystore file, truststore with imported CA, the listing of both shows that certificates are inside.

But I receive the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
    at ...

...

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
    at sun.security.validator.EndEntityChecker.checkTLSServer(EndEntityChecker.java:270)
    at sun.security.validator.EndEntityChecker.check(EndEntityChecker.java:141)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319)
... 29 more
```

Viewing the certificate contents in the part of Extensions I see the following:

```
Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 33 87 72 1D 09 2F DF FF   1A A7 D1 C0 E1 CF C5 FA  3.r../..........
0010: A4 19 54 2E                                        ..T.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
   SSL client
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 74 9F 43 07 CC 75 FA D3   D0 13 0F 65 36 CC 4A 9A  t.C..u.....e6.J.
0010: E0 8E 9C 52                                        ...R
]
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://test.az:7447/Test%20CA.crl]
]]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
]
```

So my certificate does contain **KeyUsage [ DigitalSignature ]**

The code snippet of the place throwing the exception looks like the following:

```
private final static int KU_SIGNATURE = 0;

...

private void checkTLSServer(X509Certificate cert, String parameter)
        throws CertificateException {
    Set<String> exts = getCriticalExtensions(cert);

    ...

    } else if (KU_SERVER_SIGNATURE.contains(parameter)) {
        if (checkKeyUsage(cert, KU_SIGNATURE) == false) {
            throw new ValidatorException
                    ("KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures",
                    ValidatorException.T_EE_EXTENSIONS, cert);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and **checkKeyUsage** function:

```
private boolean checkKeyUsage(X509Certificate cert, int bit)
        throws CertificateException {
    boolean[] keyUsage = cert.getKeyUsage();
    if (keyUsage == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return (keyUsage.length > bit) && keyUsage[bit];
}
```

it fails in **return (keyUsage.length > bit) && keyUsage[bit];**

The question is why the result of above expression = false? When bit = 0 and cert.getKeyUsage() must return an array of boolean [true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]

Comment: Have you checked all the certificates in the chain (in particular, the CA certs)?

Comment: Yes, in fact I use keystore and truststore from my old server which runs JRE6 and there is no problem on it, but the new one with JRE7 throws above exception.

Comment: Do you get anything more precise when using `-Djavax.net.debug=all`?

Comment: What version of Java 7 did you use exactly?

Comment: Sorry, the question was a bit wrong, edited the footer.

Comment: java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: I would suggest trying with a more recent version of Java 7 to rule out the possibility of a bug in an earlier version.

Comment: Just tried to run it with java 6 and it works fine on the new server. What can be the reason for this? Maybe because of the keystore/truststore generated with previous keytool version?

Comment: Are you running it all with the same client certificate and keystore? Can you see any more details with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`? Is it possible that the key usage refers to something to do with your CA certificate and your CRL distribution point `http://test.az:7447/Test%20CA.crl`?

Comment: Could the issue be with the server certificate instead of the client certificate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error actually comes from verifying the server's certificate.  That certificate has a key usage section that doesn't include a digitalSignature bit.

Some cipher suites require the digital signature bit, specifically Diffie-Hellman key exchange (DHE_RSA and ECDHE_RSA).  You may be able to avoid this error by avoiding those cipher types.  Otherwise the server certificate needs to support it.

Comment: And how does one avoid using these ciphers from within java?

Answer (score 1):

this error happened also to me and while the answer of @Chris D is correct I thought about giving you a way to overcome this issue.

We are in a situation where our Java application has to talk with a server through HTTPS. If we are able to tune this server's TLS we can solve the issue.

Basically we need to disable all the ciphers based on Diffie Hellman on the HTTPS server. You need to exclude all ciphers which contain `DH`.

In case of Haproxy I used these directives:

```
global
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

In case of a Java HTTPS server I've set this env var:

```
SERVER_SSL_CIPHERS=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

which will then be translated to the Java property [server.ssl.ciphers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server.ssl.ciphers)

---

If you want to force some ciphers on the client-side, this SO question might be what you're looking for [Java - How can I disable a TLS cipher for only some protocols using JVM Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779312/java-how-can-i-disable-a-tls-cipher-for-only-some-protocols-using-jvm-config/52814980)

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that this behavior is still the same for the latest JRE version (19).

There seems to be another way how to avoid the problem (beside the one mentioned by Chris D). It looks like when a [trust anchor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_anchor) is present inside the truststore java does not trigger the checks responsible for throwing the described exception and blindly trust to the server's certificate.

The related code can be saw here:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/4cec141a90bc5d3b8ec17c024291d9c74a112cd4/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/validator/Validator.java#L259

This means importing the server's certificate directly into the java's truststore resolves the issue.