# Java - How can I disable a TLS cipher for only some protocols using JVM Config?

Tags: java, java-8

I've seen lots of examples of disabling TLS ciphers in java using [jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms), for example:

```
 jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

**But how can I disable a cipher for only certain protocols, using `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` or a similar config?**

For example, how can I disable `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` for `TLSv1.1` only?

It doesn't seem to support the `opensssl` way of doing this, which is like so:

```
TLSv1.1:!TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

It doesnt cause any errors, but the cipher is still allowed.

EDIT: Note that I'm only really interested in JVM config based answers, as I don't control the code that's on lots of these servers, just the JVM and JVM configurations. Some are even 3rd party servers, so more of an ops level thing than anything.

EDIT 2: Note that you can run a java app and supply arguments that change which protocols and ciphers are used, e.g. `java -server -Djava.security.properties=./my/custom/java.security -jar myapp.jar` will do it - but it wont let you filter ciphers by protocol, only ciphers, or protocols, from what I can see. The file would contain a property entry like `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`

Comment: Note about your edit : I'm not sure what you are looking for is totally achiveable. If you were running J2SE applications only, maybe, but if you' running, say fullscale J2EE containers (Weblogic and the like), then you're not even sure the SSL is fully controlled by JSSE configurations, most likely there are server specific overlays that may, or may not honor JSSE configuration flags. Security wise, I'd be suspicious of a "command line argument" solution that is supposed to control SSL/TLS over *any* kind of java app. But I'm not a Weblogic/Sphere/JoNAS/TomEE/GlassFish/... expert.

Comment: (continued): just as an example, here is an article on "how to use JSSE implementation for SSL on Weblogic Fusion". it mentions that by default, there were version that did not use JSSE... https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SECMG/ssl_jsse_impl.htm#SECMG494

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - you can definitely run a java app and supply arguments that change which protocols and ciphers are used, e.g. `java -server -Djava.security.properties=./my/custom/java.security -jar myapp.jar` will do it - but it wont let you filter ciphers by protocol, only ciphers, or protocols, from what I can see. I'll add this to my edit as a 2nd edit!

Comment: Since you are on the DevOps side, maybe you can run separate instances of the app, each one having only TLSv1.1, only TLSv1.2 etc. enabled, apply the desired cipher filter to each one, and then have nginx or whatever redirect traffic to the appropriate instance depending on the detected protocol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer because why not.

Other answers, and every doc I've found online, seems to agree that what you are asking for is not possible to do within Java, not yet at least. You can enable / disable protocols globally, and you can enable / disable cipher types globally, but you cannot do one based on the other.

However, since you are on the DevOps side, maybe a non-Java solution is possible. You could run separate instances of the app, each one having only TLSv1.1, only TLSv1.2 etc. enabled, and apply the desired cipher filter to each one; and then have nginx (or whatever you use) redirect traffic to the appropriate instance depending on the detected protocol.

So, one instance at NODE1 with:

```
jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

Another instance at NODE2 with:

```
jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=...
```

And some nginx rules (use `return` or `rewrite` as you see fit):

```
server {
    [...]
    if ( $ssl_protocol = TLSv1.1 ) {
        return 302 $scheme://NODE1.yourhost.com$request_uri;
    }
    if ( $ssl_protocol = TLSv1.2 ) {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://NODE2.yourhost.com$request_uri;
    }
```

I'm just a Java dev, my experience with nginx is very limited so you might need to tweak the config a bit. Just trying to help.

Comment: hey.... i think this is actually the best answer that aligns with my question - i don't think we'll be able to do it for logistical reasons here where I work, but still... great idea... thanks! Unless a way better answer shows up, I'm going to award you a bounty as well.

Comment: Well that's very nice of you! I hope you find a "doable" answer anyway :)

Answer (score 7):

[JSSE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms) say that the `https.protocols` property can store comma separated list of supported protocols in a given SSL context, however this property is used by current JSSE implementation, but could be disregarded by other vendors or future versions, so YMMV.

**Programatically** you can achieve it like so:

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {
    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5.javaName,
    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA.javaName,
});

//allow TLS1.2 only
socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {
    TlsVersion.TLS_1_2.javaName,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... I'm mostly interested in config only options though, as I don't control the code that's on lots of these servers, just the JVM and JVM configurations. Some are even 3rd party servers, so more of an ops thing than anything. If I don't get any config based answers, I'll give it to you ;-) I've added this as a clarification to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... after reviewing this, i'm not convinced this would actually do it, would it? It seems like it'd work for your use case, only enabling TLS1.2, but what if you wanted to enable cipher A for TLS 1.2, and not for TLS1.1 ?

Comment: @BradParks I don't think you could automatically correlate cipher with protocol. What you do is just enabling some ciphers AND some protocols.

Comment: hey... thanks again for the response - i've been able to do that for awhile now, but think that there might be a time when I want to disable a cipher for a certain protocol, ie - not for all protocols. Maybe that doesnt make sense, but I do know I cant blindly disable all ciphers used by TLSv1 - if I do, they're not available to TLSv1.1 for example. I can, as you suggest, disable TLSv1 as a protcol, and then disable only the ciphers that I want to disable in TLSv1.1/1.2, but wonder if a time is coming when they wont sync up.

Answer (score 0):

edit `lib/security/java.security` (could be in a different location based on your JDK) and add the `Algorithm` to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`

In addition to that `keySize` could be used to restrict weaker algorithms. 
`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD4, MD5, EC keySize < 160, RSA keySize < 2048, DSA keySize < 2048`

I suppose, you already know all these, and are really looking to have these per version (ideally something like `jdk.tls11.disabledAlgorithms`)
however, I am not aware of any such fine grained property.

However, protocol version could be restricted as such `jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1`

If you want to support `TLSv1.1` and `TLSv1.2` a good strategy would be to support only those algorithms (or adjust keySize of algorithms) so that they will be strong in both versions of TLS.

For reference: https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I aware of the above, but am required to block on a per cipher basis, by protocol, sadly.... So far I'm blocking TLSv1, and then blocking individual ciphers in TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, which luckily sync up, but I expect very soon may not as other protocols are introduced, e.g. TLSv1.3. Thanks!